# Erro na função Pivot do SQL

Tags: sql-server

Primeira dúvida:
A Coluna que se transformará em Linha (nesse caso especifico o cabeçalho) pode se repetir ? Tenho vários registros que se repetem, Exemplo a Coluna **Descrição**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tab1') IS NOT NULL 
begin
    drop table #tab1
end

go

create table #tab1(
Id int null,
Nome varchar(50) null,
CNPJ varchar(50) null,
Descricao varchar(50) null,
Situacao varchar(50) null
)

insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (1,'Empresa1','8439659000150','Descricao1','Positivo')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (1,'Empresa1','8439659000150','Descricao2','Regular')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (1,'Empresa1','8439659000150','Descricao3','Irregular')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (2,'Empresa2','8439659000231','Descricao1','Positivo')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (2,'Empresa2','8439659000231','Descricao2','Regular')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (2,'Empresa2','8439659000231','Descricao3','Irregular')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (3,'Empresa3','11594952000105','Descricao1','Positivo')
insert into #tab1 (Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao) values (3,'Empresa3','11594952000105','Descricao2','Regular')

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @COLUNAS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COLUNAS = ''

SELECT @COLUNAS = COALESCE(@COLUNAS + '[' + (CAST(Descricao AS NVARCHAR(255))) + '],','')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Descricao FROM #tab1) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS
SET @COLUNAS = LEFT (@COLUNAS, LEN(@COLUNAS)-1)

DECLARE @SQLSTRING NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLSTRING = N'
SELECT * FROM(SELECT Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao FROM #tab1) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS
PIVOT(Situacao FOR Descricao IN('+@COLUNAS+')) AS PivotTable;'

 EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTRING
```

Outro problema que ocorre erro:

```
Mensagem 156, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 13
Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'FOR'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Falta a função de agregação

Você precisa definir ao menos uma função de agregação para o `PIVOT`.

Exemplo:

```
SET @SQLSTRING = N'
SELECT * FROM(SELECT Id, Nome, CNPJ, Descricao, Situacao FROM #tab1) AS DADOS_HORIZONTAIS
PIVOT(MIN(Situacao) FOR Descricao IN('+@COLUNAS+')) AS PivotTable;'
```